# object not rotating properly after translate transform in wpf?

Tags: wpf, transform

I have canvas with several cutom controls inherited from panel class, dynamically added to it at runtime with rendertransform=(.5,.5). But when apply translate transform (50,50) and rotate it by 100 degrees, it does not rotate on its place, it rotates in radius of 50, why? 
Am I doing wrong something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transformations are not commutative, you should apply the rotation before applying the translation.

Often you have a TransformGroup, then you can just change the order of its children, if this is somehow not an option because some transform is "inherited" from a parent you can nullify prior transforms using their inverse (in the case of a translation that should move the target back to the origin), then you can rotate it in place, and apply the original transform again.

---

The documentation is your friend, here is what can be found for [`TransformGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup.aspx):

> In a composite transformation, the order of individual transformations is important. For example, if you first rotate, then scale, then translate, you get a different result than if you first translate, then rotate, then scale. One reason order is significant is that transformations like rotation and scaling are done with respect to the origin of the coordinate system. Scaling an object that is centered at the origin produces a different result than scaling an object that has been moved away from the origin. Similarly, rotating an object that is centered at the origin produces a different result than rotating an object that has been moved away from the origin.

Comment: I have both transforms in a TransformGroup to applied RenderTransform

Comment: Is there a possibility you can give a code example for this solution, i have the same problem however since i generate the "to be rotated" objects in my c# code straight from the database, any xaml example is irrelevant. And i dont want to post a duplicate question.

Comment: @ThrowingDwarf: "any xaml example is irrelevant", that's kind of nonsense. 1. In the vast majority of cases (like in this) there is a trivial and direct translation from XAML to C#. 2. WPF was designed around dynamic and changing content, hence all its data binding and templating features, data coming from a DB or API is not an excuse to throw out XAML and write spaghetti code.

Comment: The reason behind this is because the position and angle of the buttons is stored in a database. The buttons are generated on runtime. They need to be able to rotate ad move. And they do both, however when i click on a rotated button(counter clockwise 90deg for example) on a certain position (for example left top). You are actually clicking the upper right corner. My problem is that the buttons snaps the cursor to the position that would have been clicked if it was not rotated. This might seem a bit vague but it is hard to explain.

Comment: And since they(unknown amount) are generated from runtime they dont have any hardcoded xaml. Everything is set in c#.

Comment: @ThrowingDwarf: The amount does not matter, you can bind to an `ItemsControl` and it can create as many `Buttons` as there are. Likewise you can bind all the values on the transforms to properties of the items, like rotation and translation. There still is no need for C# here (with the exception of fetching the data and placing it in view models). I don't understand your click and rotation problem though.

Comment: there are multiple types of buttons, eacht with a stackpanel and a different image. Think of a map of a restaurant with tables. The tables need to be able to move and rotate, and ofcourse it should be possible to add new tables, or to remove them. Since orders are bound to a table or button i should be able to acces them directly. The rotation problem is likely to be solved. It does still need some refining but it should be done by the end of the week.

Comment: @ThrowingDwarf: That sounds perfectly within what i described. It's quite common that people what to [bind items with positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672063/how-to-bind-a-canvas-to-a-list-of-rectangles/5672085#5672085). And for detecting clicks just bind the `Command` of the `Button` to a command on your view model.

Comment: I needed something like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/47c7be7f-e3e7-4e50-8b32-93d9c4c5d34d/-move-ui-element-after-rotation-with-mouse-dragging?forum=wpf This really helped me a lot. I do not want to clutter the xaml code. The last things that still need to be done are the lines that mark the original position to be rotated as well. and figuring out how to do this. This is probably done by getting the new coördinates and setting the lines to those positions. as well as rotating the rectangle that markes the old pos.I might upload this as a question in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

If it rotates with a radius of 50, it's because your origin is wrong.

You just need to change the origin of your `RotateTransform` by setting the `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties both to `50` in this case.

Comment: Is has not effect, since i applied rendertransform=(.5,.5)

Comment: What did you set the `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties to be?

Comment: nothing. It works when rendertransformorigin=(.5,.5) is applied