# Reference point for lines in list view

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to show some lines on a canvas,Those lines vary in Y axis position ,So created  an itemscontrol and binded to a dictionary which has Y value and some text to display on line .

My problem is that line are getting displayed to (x1,y1)(x2,y2) point with reference to individual item's origin but I want each line to take Y axis distance from canvas origin point.

```
<Canvas Margin="0,8,0,8" Height="374" Width="150"  >
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YPointsDictionary Margin="0">

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Line  X1="0" Y1="{Binding Value}" X2="150" Y2="{Binding Value}" 
              StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Yellow" StrokeDashArray="2,2"  />
         <Label Content="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Yellow" />                 
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
  </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here.I need to bind the canvas left and top as X and Y origin of each item.
[How to bind a canvas to a list of rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672063/how-to-bind-a-canvas-to-a-list-of-rectangles?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Making the stackPanel Orientation vertical gives the result. Is this what you want?

eg:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  >
        <Line X1="0" Y1="50" X2="150" Y2="50" Stroke="red" StrokeThickness="5"></Line>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="100" X2="150" Y2="100" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5"></Line>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="150" X2="150" Y2="150" Stroke="green" StrokeThickness="5"></Line>
    </StackPanel>
```